# Difference between Do/While and While/Do

Tags: c#, winforms, do-while

I am trying to learn C# and I want to take this code I wrote and see if I can change it and use do/while and while/do in it. I have been messing with this all day and I have a hard time grasping the do/while and while/do for some reason. If anyone can show me how it would be great. Also, if you do or can, please explain it a bit too. Trying to learn, but I'm puzzled.

```
private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int answer = 0;
    //int i = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    int j = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    int multiplyBy = int.Parse(multiplier.Text);

    for (int i = int.Parse(textBox3.Text); i <= j; i++)
    {
        //answer = answer + i;
        //listBox1.Items.Add(answer.ToString());
        answer = multiplyBy * i;
        listBox1.Items.Add(i + " times" + multiplyBy + " = " + answer.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: So your book doesn't explain how `do/while` and `while` work?

Comment: It does, but for some reason I'm having a mental block. Im really new to programming and I've been doing a lot of different things. Im not understanding it well. If you don't want to help, you don't need to.

Comment: Where are you trying to use the `do/while` and `while` mechanisms?  You need to supply ALL of the code from your book.  The snippet you posted isn't comprehensive enough.

Comment: I'm not sure how you wouldn't grasp the concept of `do/while`. It's just english, all you have to know is how the syntax works. Which is really just `do { } while (condition)`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Wanted to see if I can do it or not with this code.

Comment: @user2856358: is there anything special in *this* code? Just write some another examples instead. Then one day after you become confident - you rewrite this piece. PS: "If you don't want to help, you don't need to" --- you're confusing learning with doing your job for free by someone. If you don't want to learn - you don't need to, just forget it and have some beer instead.

Comment: "Wanted to see if I can do it or not with this code." --- it's obvious  that *you* cannot do that. It's still technically possible though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `while ( condition ) { LoopBody() }`
  executes `LoopBody()` zero or more times.

  `condition` is checked **prior** to executing the loop body: so long as `condition` is `true`, the loop body is executed.
- `do { LoopBody() } while ( condition )`
  executes `LoopBody()` one or more times.

  `condition` is checked **after** executing the loop body. It is the **exact** equivalent of

  ```
  LoopBody() ;
  while ( condition )
  {
    LoopBody() ;
  }
  ```

One should note that if the body of the loop never changes the condition, the loop while never terminate.

Edited to note: `for` is for all intents and purposes a while loop. Your `for` loop:

```
for (int i = int.Parse(textBox3.Text); i <= j; i++)
{
  LoopBody() ;
}
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
int i = int.Parse(textBox3.Text) ;
while ( i <= j )
{
  LoopBody() ;
  i++ ;
}
```

The "roughly bit is because the loop indexer is scoped to the `for` loop as if it were written

{ // introduces a scope
      int i = int.Parse(textBox3.Text) ;
      while ( i <= j )
      {
        LoopBody() ;
        i++ ;
      }
    } // end of scope

And that's not quite the same as the for loop, because were you to introduce a new `i` in the method, you'd get a compiler whine about duplicate variable names. A `for`-loop doesn't have that problem. The compiler is perfectly happy with something like this:

```
if ( condition-A )
{
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i )
  {
     DoSomethingUseful(i) ;
  }
}
else
{
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i )
  {
     DoSomethingElseUseful(i) ;
  }
}
```

whereas something like this would cause the compiler to whine:

```
if ( condition-A )
{
  int i = 0 ;
  while ( i < 10 )
  {
     DoSomethingUseful(i) ;
     ++i ;
  }
}
else
{
  int i = 0 ;
  while ( i < 10 )
  {
     DoSomethingElseUseful(i) ;
     ++i ;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Refactoring your code to use a `while` loop would give you something like this:

```
private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int i          = int.Parse( textBox3.Text   ) ;
  int j          = int.Parse( textBox2.Text   ) ;
  int multiplyBy = int.Parse( multiplier.Text ) ;

  while ( i <= j )
  {
    int    answer = multiplyBy * i ;
    string value  = string.Format( "{0} times {1} = {2}" , i , mulitplyBy , answer ) ;

    listBox1.Items.Add( value ) ;

    ++i ;
  }

  return ;
}
```

Comment: "if the body of the loop never changes the condition, the loop while never terminate" --- it's not entirely correct. Not only the body can/must change the condition, but the condition can change naturally. Like time based comparisons or comparisons with random numbers

Comment: I believe this answer is enough to get @user2856358 started applying `do/while `and `while` in the code on his own.

Answer (score 0):

The general form of `do/while` looks like this:

```
do
{
   // Perform some actions here.
} while (some condition);  // Break out of the loop once this condition is satisfied.
```

The 'some condition' is of type `bool`.  The main difference between a `do/while` and a `while` is that if 'some condition' is false at the beginning of the do loop, the body of the loop will *not be executed*.

The basic point of the `do/while` loop is to spin through the loop performing some action or actions and then break out of the loop once your `while` condition is satisfied.  For reference, you can see a very simple example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/370s1zax.aspx) from MSDN.  For the most part, as you gain more experience, you will likely find yourself using [for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ch45axte.aspx), [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [while](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2aeyhxcd.aspx) loops over the do/while variety.

Comment: Oops, you are correct.  I was going to incorporate an example loop in his code then thought better of it.  I removed the example as it was horrible.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `do/while` when your body of loop MUST execute at least one time, else, use `while`.